# How to get width and height of non JPG image with fetching 26 bytes in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I want to get width and height of image stored in Google cloud storage without loading it in memory.

I found answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550603/8847604) stating that if image type is not `JPEG` or `TIFF` then we can get width and height of image by only loading 26 bytes in memory. but I'm unable to figured out way of doing that.

I didn't find any code snippets or article related that.

also I was wondering that if same can achieve by using `PNG` image which will be created by `get_serving_url()` trasformation on the fly. and loading 26 bytes of that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll take a stab.  Try this:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
import urllib2

image_url   = "http://....."

req         = urllib2.Request(image_url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-30'})
resp        = urllib2.urlopen(req)
image_bytes = resp.read()
image       = images.Image(image_bytes)

print image.width 
print image.height

resp.close()
```

Comment: `urlopen(req)` gives error :HTTPError: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable.

Comment: What is the file size of the image? Try `'bytes=0-1'` or `'bytes=1-2'` to diagnose.

Comment: file size is more than 5MB. using `'bytes=0-1' or 'bytes=1-2'` gives same error.

Comment: Please post entire error message.  It should contain something like `Content-Range: bytes */47022`

Comment: File "urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Comment: This code works.  I used `image_url="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"`.  What URL are you using?

Comment: in my case it worked after i changed bytes to 30 from 25